# jenkins notifying error occured in different steps by sending mail in Pipeline (former known as Workflow)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline with multiple steps, for example:

```
stage 'dev - compile'
node('master') {
  //do something
}

stage 'test- compile'
node('master') {
    //do something
}

stage 'prod- compile'
node('master') {
    //do something
}
```

I want to send a email if something goes wrong in the job, how can I send an email no matter where the error got triggered, something like:

```
try {
 /** 
  all the code above
  **/
 } catch(Exception e) { 
     mail the error
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Jenkins 'Mailer' inside pipeline workflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169100/use-jenkins-mailer-inside-pipeline-workflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did to include useful information in my mail about the failure:

```
try {
    stage 'checkout cvs'
    node('master') {
        /** CODE **/
    }

    stage 'compile'
    node('master') {
        /** CODE **/
    }

    stage 'test unit'
    node('master') {
        /** CODE **/
    }   

    stage 'package'
    node('master') {
        /** CODE **/
    }

    stage 'nexus publish'
    node('master') {
        /** CODE **/
    }

    stage 'Deploy to App Server'
    node('master') {
        /** CODE **/            
    }

} catch(e) {
    String error = "${e}";
    // Make the string with job info, example:
    // ${env.JOB_NAME}
    // ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} 
    // ${env.BUILD_URL}
    // and other variables in the code
    mail bcc: '',
         cc: '',
         charset: 'UTF-8',
         from: '',
         mimeType: 'text/html',
         replyTo: '',
         subject: "ERROR CI: Project name -> ${env.JOB_NAME}",
         to: "${mails_to_notify}",
         body: "<b>${pivote}</b><br>\n\nMensaje de error: ${error}\n\n<br>Projecto: ${env.JOB_NAME} <br>Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} <br> URL de build: ${env.BUILD_URL}";
    error "${error}"
}
```

Comment: This would send the email when you abort the job too.

Comment: And that it is what I want, I mean if something gives me an error, so notify the error

Answer (score 8):

I think it is a better way to use the jenkins build in [post section](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/#cleaning-up-and-notifications) instead of using try catch:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    stages {
      stage('whatever') {
        steps {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
    post {
        always {
          step([$class: 'Mailer',
            notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true,
            recipients: "example@example.com",
            sendToIndividuals: true])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch!  I wish I understood why the Mailer plugin isn't exposed more nicely in the declarative pipeline instead of the lower-level `mail()` which requires much more assembly.  Probably 95% of the users are happy with the emails generated by the Mailer plugin...

Answer (score 3):

Well, your idea is absolutely correct, you just need to move `mail` after the `catch` block or use `finally`. Examples (in pseudocode):

```
try {
    //code
    email = 'success'
} catch(Exception e) { 
    // error handler: logging
    email = 'failure'
}
send email
```

Or the same approach using the `catchError` pipeline built-in:

```
result = 'failure'
catchError { // this catches all exceptions and set the build result
    //code
    result = 'success' // we will reach this point only if no exception was thrown
}
send result
```

Or using `finally`:

```
try {
    //code
} finally { 
    send email
}
```

Comment: I think if I use the finally I will send always the email, I just want to notify when the buils it's broken. Also, I tried catchError {
    echo 'ERROR MY FRIEND';
} and I put some wrong IP in GIT and I did not get my echo 'ERROR MY FRIEND'

Comment: I might misunderstand your question. If you want to send email only when an error occured, you initial code snippet fits perfectly. As for `catchError` it doesn't block any logging.

Comment: I will try my code , I didn't to be honest, I just thought that wasn't work

Comment: I also edited the `catchError` example so that it can maintain the build result.

Comment: I don't think the original code snippet will work, unless you put everything into that try {...} catch block. I'm also wondering whether there is a solution like job failure listener/hook.