# use publishHTML in Jenkinsfile on fail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-2, jenkins-pipeline

currently I have this in my Jenkinsfile:

```
sh "./gradlew spoon${flavorCombination}"
publishHTML(target:[allowMissing: true, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, keepAll: true, reportDir: "android/build/spoon-output/${flavorCombination}DebugAndroidTest", reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'Spoon'])
```

this works fine when the spoon-tests pass - I am able to see my result reports then. But unfortunately when the tests fail they do not get published - but especially then I would like to look into the reports. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Check this question and its answer that cover emailng: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948606/jenkins-notifying-error-by-sending-mail-in-pipeline-former-known-as-workflow

Comment: Use `try{...}finally{...}`